# How to get a list in a MessageBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I display the contents of a `string` list in the body of a message box?

Here's what I have so far:

```
List<string> a = new List<string> {}; 
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells) 
{ 
    a.Add(cell.Value.ToString()); 
} 

MessageBox.Show(a);  // doesn't work !?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MessageBox requires a string not a list

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells)
{
    sb.AppendLine(cell.Value.ToString()); 
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 8):

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, a));
```

This is assuming you were getting something along the lines of "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" as the message.

Comment: string.Join does not accept an enumerable list prior to .NET 4.  So, if you are using an older version of the framework, you need to convert it to an array (e.g. `a.ToArray()`).

Comment: My selected cells are: 1 2 3 4 5 (values). But in a MsgBox i got: 5 4 3 2 1 !!

Comment: @Bonaca: Try `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, a.OrderBy(x => x))); `

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string> list = new List<string> {}; 

foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells) 
{ 
a.Add(cell.Value.ToString()); 
} 

string s = String.Join(",", list);

MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

`MessageBox.Show` requires a string. If you need it in this format, you could build it like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells.OrderBy(c => c.Index))
    builder.AppendLine(cell.Value);
}

MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

If you need a more sophisticated output, you may need to create a new form to show it.

Comment: hangy I wrote your code and got inverse string. My cellValues are: 1 2 3 4 5 and i got 5 4 3 2 1 !!

Comment: Edited my answer. I suppose you need them to be ordered in the cell index order, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515769/11963?

Answer (score 3):

MessageBox.Show takes an string as parameter.

```
string result;
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells) 
{ 
   //choose one
   //result += cell.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
   //or
   result = cell.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + result;
} 

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: PowerRoy, I wrote your code and got inverse string. My cellValues are: 1 2 3 4 5 and i got 5 4 3 2 1 !!

Comment: This means your selected cells are in the wrong order. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

MessageBox cannot show any data type other than a string.  You will need to format the list as a string such as:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", a.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    if (cell.ValueType == typeof(String))
    {
        builder.Append(cell.Value);
    } 
}
MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

Note, you will need to start formatting your questions correctly if you want to avoid down votes.

I hope this helps.

**Edit:** Or...

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ValueType == typeof(String))
        builder.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: My selected cells are: 1 2 3 4 5 (values). But in a MsgBox i got: 5 4 3 2 1 !!

Comment: use `builder.ToString().Reverse();` if this is what you need.