# How can I display a list of data from database in a messagebox with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using WinForms and c#, and I want to display the list of employees with an expiry card date.  I have tried the code below:

```
DataManager.NotificationManager obj = new DataManager.NotificationManager();
DataTable dt1 = obj.GetListExpiryDate();
DateTime currendate = DateTime.Today;

foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    if (DateTime.Parse(row.ItemArray[41].ToString()) == currendate)
    {                   
        MessageBox.Show("Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"]);
    }
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetListExpiryDate]  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *    
    FROM MST_Employee  
END
```

I need to display the list of the employees with expiry card date in the messagebox, but the problem it that only displays the first one. Any ideas please?

Comment: Keep appending to a string or use string builder and set that string as messagebox's text

Comment: Also its dangerous to pull out select * from db and use an itemarray index to fetch data. `row["ExpiryDate"]` would be more safe

Comment: thanks @Rohit but can you help me with some code please ?

Comment: I have added a sample code on your request. These kind of stuffs are trivial and could be found by just searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this is what you want to accomplish. For better performances use a `StringBuilder` instead of `string`

```
string message = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
      if (DateTime.Parse(row.ItemArray[41].ToString()) == currendate)
      {
          message += "Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"] + "\n";
      }
}
 MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Also use `row["columnname"]` instead of `row.ItemArray[41]`

*`String.Builder` version* :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
      if (DateTime.Parse(row.ItemArray[41].ToString()) == currendate)
      {
          sb.AppendLine("Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"]); 
      }
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

You might also want to have a look at the answers in this SO Question, [How to get a list in a MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904390/how-to-get-a-list-in-a-messagebox.)